# How can I seek to a particular location in a video thru this videojs library?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I seek to a particular location in video using videojs api?

Comment: Have you Googled `videojs seek`?

Comment: Next time consult the documentation, asking questions like this is just plain lazy.

Comment: @pekka: if its duplicate then why dont you flag it

Comment: @dreamweiver why should I *flag* it as duplicate instead of voting to close it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var player = VideoJS.setup("my_video");
player.play();
player.currentTime(1337);
```

I can't believe you couldn't find this on Google...

Answer (score 0):

The [API](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md) documentation is a good place to start, in particular the [`.currentTime(seconds)`](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md#currenttimeseconds--type-integer-or-float) function.